# Ver duração de um vídeo do Youtube?

Tags: php, youtube

Como é possível ver o tempo de um vídeo através do `id` do vídeo?

Com alguma pesquisa encontrei como ver o título mas não consegui encontrar a duração.

```
    $content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$id_vid);
    parse_str($content, $ytarr);
    $titulo_v = $ytarr['title'];
```

Com o código acima mostrado, eu consigo ver o título do vídeo mas como faço com a duração? É possível da mesma forma?

Comment: tem que ver quais são os dados de retorno, dê um print_r na variável $ytarr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro da variável `$ytarr` tem o índice `length_seconds` que traz a duração do vídeo em segundos:

```
$seconds = $ytarr['length_seconds'];
```

Comment: Fiz o `print_r` e descobri isso também, irei aceitar esta resposta assim que puder, funcionou na perfeição